# .htaccess pw protected folder refresh to access page?

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, .htpasswd

I am using a **.htaccess** file to pw protect a downloads folder.  The website links to the files contained in the folder, and that works to some degree.  When one clicks on a webpage link to the file in the folder, it pops up a login box, but goes to the file in the directory, rather than leaving them on the webpage from which they are accessing the file.  This only occurs in the first instance of login, but after that, it works perfectly.  To explain further, user goes to webpage, clicks link, **.htaccess** login pop-up displays, login occurs, but it displays only this file and path in the browser.  I am an avid front end designer, but when it comes to the back end, please over explain.

I tried throwing in an html file with an auto refresh to the previous page, but it doesn't load that file.

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access restricted"
AuthUserFile /home/dir/.members
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AddType application/octet-stream .zip
AddType application/octet-stream .exe
require valid-user

Comment: I can offer an explanation, but not necessarily a solution :-) Browsers are able to recognize that something is not a "navigation" action (move to a different page), when the headers indicate that the response is not something to be displayed directly, but should trigger a download dialog. In that case, they make the user "stay" on the current page, and don't change the address bar either. But with your authentication, the server does initially not respond with the requested document - but sends a 401 Unauthorized response first, to prompt the client to supply credentials. [...]

Comment: [...] And now the browser is not able to recognize any more, at that point, that the requested resource is something to be downloaded - it thinks this is a normal "navigation" action now, and therefor it "goes to" the file, as you put it. The same thing does not happen any more for the next file you request - because now the browser has the credentials already cached, and sends them without being prompted to do so by that intermediary 401 response. So it will _immediately_ get a response saying, "this is a download, not navigation to a different page."

Comment: I am not sure if there could be any way around this, by configuring a 401 error document, and having that respond with a Content-Type header of `application/octet-stream` as well. The response the client usually gets in a 401 situation, is an error document returned as `text/html`. It _could be_ that browsers could be tricked into the desired behavior this way, but I have no idea whether that would actually work.